# Why is my simple relay circuit only half working?

Tags: relay, troubleshooting

I am new to electronics and I am following the book "Make: Electronics" by Charles Platt.

I have built a circuit with a 12V DC power supply, a 1K resistor, a relay, two LEDs, and a momentary-on switch.

[image]

When I turn on the power supply, one of the LEDs lights up. However, when I press the switch down (and hold it down) that LED goes out but the other one does not light up at all.

I have made sure all connections are good, and I have replaced every single component in the circuit, but it just doesn't seem to be working.

The only thing I can think of is that I was mis-sold a relay by Maplin. I asked for a "DPDT non-latching 12V DC relay" as it says in the book. The one I have has "1A 125V AC" and "2A 24V DC" written on it.

Any suggestions? Cheers.

Comment: Check again the polarity of the non-working LED.

Comment: @Cornelius Thanks for the suggestion, I had already done that also, just to make sure.

Comment: Do you hear the relay 'clicking' when you press the button? What happens when you swap the LEDs?

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen Yes, I can hear the click. If I swap the LEDs I get the same result :(

Comment: Link to the relay? If the LED was originally put the wrong way round you'll likely have killed it so try a new led.

Comment: @Andyaka Hooking up an LED backwards should not harm it, as long as the series resistor is in place.  There are even bi-color LEDs made up of a red LED and a green LED in the same package connected head to tail, where only one lights depending on the polarity applied.

Comment: As a quickie - swap the two LEDs at the relay. Now, if the problem is reversed (no LED at power-on, LED lights when switch is pressed) you know one of the LEDs is bad.

Comment: @Andyaka I have tried a new LED but that does not seem to be an issue. Note: If I unplug the LEDS from the relay and swap them around, then the other lights up but I still have the problem of *only* one ever lighting.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast See my other comment. BTW, I *always* have one LED lit, the switch (which springs back if I let go) is just there to select which one is lit, AFAIK.

Comment: @tcrosley Not true dude. Most LEDs I've seen have an absolute maximum reverse voltage of about 5 volts and putting one the wrong way round (even via a resistor) on a 12 volt supply will likely damage it.

Comment: @User17670 part number/link/maplin number for the relay please

Comment: @Andyaka By part number, the relay on my receipt is the following: http://www.maplin.co.uk/p/12v-dc-1a-dpdt-miniature-relay-n04aw The relay I have on my workspace is black, and has writing on it as given in the question.

Comment: Try rewiring it as per my answer dude. Not all relays are wired the same. Pins 4 and 13 are poles of the changeover contacts not pins 6 and 11.

Comment: @User17670 I have a suggestion. Replace that relay and try again. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've wired it up incorrectly. See this : -

[image]

Try swapping the wires to the two most central pins. I got this PCB detail from [here](http://www.ic-key.com/pdf/MR64_47.pdf) and although it is not the same part it is classified as a BT type 47. The Maplin link doesn't show the wiring so hopefully this one will be compatible.

Comment: If I swap the LEDs on to pins 6 and 11, leaving the switch on pin 8 and the power on pins 1 and 16, I get the same problem unfortunately.

Comment: Read what I said, the two middle pins you are using need to be swapped i.e. swap pin 4 wiring to pin 6 and the former pin 6 wiring to pin 4. Also, look at the circuit diagram on the relay picture - pin 4 is where power in goes to the switch and clearly pin 6 is one LED output and pin 8 is the other. Contacts 9, 11 and 13 are not required for this experiment.

Comment: BTW, is it normal that relays (or components in general) do not come with wiring diagrams? Is it normal that I should expect a 'BT Type 47' style, or would I just be expected to mess around and find out for myself? IDK what the expectations are in the electronics world

Comment: As a golden rule (and never broken AFAIK in years) I never buy a component that doesn't have a data sheet (.pdf file) - what the suppliers may put on their sales site may easily be mistaken or lack certain info - I always read the manufacturer's data sheet even on the most basic of components and I bet that all the regular guys on here will 100% say the same without exception.

Comment: +1. I'm near my EE degree and the only thing I learned is: read the datasheet.

Comment: @VladimirCravero did they teach you that at college or was it just something you worked out along the way? When I was at college, the internet barely existed and if you wanted info you phoned up the supplier and they snail mailed it to you. These days THERE IS NO excuse LOL

Comment: I worked it out mostly on my own since we don't do much practical courses, but I've got a couple of friends who are very passionate and we enjoy doing electronics

Answer (score 1):

1. Try to use Multimeter in continuity mode and check the contact and the pole if the multimeter is beeping. 2. Add a free wheeling diode at the relay coil  like this .[image]    hope it helps

Comment: Should I make just one continuity check, and should I do it where you have drawn the diode?

Comment: at the contacts , pole , NC , NO. Place one probe at pole and other at NC or NO and trigger the relay to check it.